# How to send an Email using JAVA code?

Tags: java, email

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEMail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
 {

  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "*********@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "********@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "465";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", host);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "*****");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
  properties.setProperty("mail.user", "*******");
  properties.setProperty("mail.password", "******");

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Create the message part 
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     // Fill the message
     messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

     // Create a multipar message
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     // Set text message part
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Part two is attachment
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     String filename = "file.txt";
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Send the complete message parts
     message.setContent(multipart );

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

I am getting the following error. 
Error:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
nested exception is:
class javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

After going through Suggestions from the same page.I have modified the code    as shown above. But, this time im getting the authentication error. Plz help me where iam wrong this time?

Comment: Are you running off a server that has the email ports firewalled?

Comment: Dont know exactly what You are asking about.

Comment: Well the server says it can't connect to SMTP on localhost port 25. are you running a mail server on the localhost?

Comment: Is there an SMTP-Daemon running at "localhost" (the machine your program is executed on)? I guess not, because javax.mail can not connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

Here, host is not the machine where you are sending the email from.(As written in comments in code).
It is the host where your e-mail server is.

For gmail - it is `smtp.gmail.com` on port 465.

You have to configure it according to your smtp server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to more properties, I can see your code and see that there is some properties are missing like

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

You also need to set Authenticator and some other things,
Please refer below Example: [Send Mail using JAVA with Gmail Account](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api-through-gmail-server)

Answer (score 0):

you can find the code here to send email using Java

http://javainfinite.com/java/send-email-using-gmail-in-java/

Answer (score -3):

personally recommend sending mails using the SMTP protocol raw, only to better understand how it works, but in answer to his problem, check whether port 25 in your firewall, should not be enabled is open, start a new rule